# AssertionError when normalizing matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, assert, assertion, normalize

I have defined the following function in Python to return a normalized version of the matrix M.

```
def get_normalized_matrix(M, O):
    M_copy = np.copy(M)
    M_copy[O == 0] = 0
    a = np.sum(M_copy) / np.sum(O)
    s = np.sqrt(np.sum((M_copy - a)**2) / np.sum(O))
    M_normalized = (M_copy - a) / s
    return M_normalized
```

After running the following check, I get an AssertionError for `assert(abs(np.sum(Mn**2 * O) / np.sum(O) - 1) < 1e-6)`.

```
def check_normalization():
    M = np.random.rand(10, 3)
    O = (np.random.rand(10, 3) > 0.5) + 0
    Mn = get_normalized_matrix(M, O)
    assert(abs(np.sum(M * O)) > 1e-6)
    assert(abs(np.sum(Mn * O)) < 1e-6)
    assert(abs(np.sum(Mn**2 * O) / np.sum(O) - 1) < 1e-6)
    print("Function {} is working fine!".format('get_normalized_matrix'))
    
check_normalization()
```

Can you help me figure out where I went wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: What are the actual results that cause the comparison to fail?

Comment: Did you mean to do `assert(abs(np.sum(Mn**2 * O) / (np.sum(O) - 1)) < 1e-6)` instead of `assert(abs(np.sum(Mn**2 * O) / np.sum(O) - 1) < 1e-6)`? Moreover, the assertion error occurs because the value returned from `abs(np.sum(Mn**2 * O) / np.sum(O) - 1)` **is less than** `1e-6`.

Answer (score 0):

The AssertionError indicates that there is a problem with the normalization of the matrix, specifically that the squared sum of the normalized matrix Mn weighted by the O matrix is not equal to 1.

One possible issue in the code could be the order of operations in the normalization step. Instead of first subtracting the mean a and then dividing by the standard deviation s, it might be more accurate to first divide by the standard deviation and then subtract the mean. This is because the order of operations can affect the numerical precision of the calculations.

To fix this, you can modify the function as follows:

```
def get_normalized_matrix(M, O):
M_copy = np.copy(M)
M_copy[O == 0] = 0
s = np.sqrt(np.sum((M_copy - np.mean(M_copy[O > 0]))**2) / np.sum(O))
M_normalized = (M_copy - np.mean(M_copy[O > 0])) / s
return M_normalized
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
assert(abs(np.sum(Mn**2 * O) / np.sum(O) - 1) < 1e-6)
```

**With**

```
assert(abs(np.sum(Mn**2 * O) / np.sum((O) - 1) < 1e-6))
```

It's a missing parenthesis